# Does passing useState as a props to an variables make issues?

Tags: reactjs

Currently, I'm trying to use useState to change a value to an object.
However, the thing I've done doesn't make any errors.
So, I want to know if the way i use UseState is making issues later.

So, my code is like this :

### this is where I make useState :

```
export const SettingContextProvider = props => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState({});
  const [label, setLabel] = useState({});
}
```

### and I pass to this component:

```
const DataSettingPage = () => {
  const { layoutValue, chartValue, MainPage } = useContext(CommonStateContext);
  const { SetTitle, SetLabel, SetDatas, SetLabels } = useContext(SettingContext);
  const [changeLayout] = layoutValue;
  const [chart] = chartValue;
  const [title, setTitle] = SetTitle;
  const [label, setLabel] = SetLabel;
      
  {chart[index].key === "Bar" && (
    <BarChart
      title={title[id]}
      label={label[id]}
    />
  )}
```

### and I'm using that state to here as a props :

```
import React from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const BarChart = ({ title, label }) => {
  let data = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: label,
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: ["#a7def8e1"],
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Bar
        data={data}
        options={{
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          plugins: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: title,
              color: "#345fbb",
              font: { size: 22 },
            },
          },
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default BarChart;
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to destructure the passed value further in your child components.

these lines aren't needed:

```
    const [title, setTitle] = SetTitle;
  const [label, setLabel] = SetLabel;
```

Also, I didn't find SetDatas and SetLabels anywhere in your code, have you defined them?

Apart from these two issues, it is perfectly fine to define a state in a parent component and pass both the value and the function to the children:

Parent:

```
    export const SettingContextProvider = props => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState({});
  const [label, setLabel] = useState({});

return (<SettingContext.Provider value={[title,setTitle,label,setLabel]}>
              <DataSettingPage/>
</SettingContext.Provider>
```

Child:

```
  const DataSettingPage = () => {
  const { layoutValue, chartValue, MainPage } = useContext(CommonStateContext);
  const [title,setTitle,label,setLabel] =
    useContext(SettingContext); // you can use them as needed

  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling [React.createContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) for your context objects? If not I believe your code may have issues as it's not the correct way to use useContext() according to React docs.

Your **BarChart** component looks like it's missing most of the data (only taking title and one label), so you should fill those in properly.

I would suggest to delete **SettingContextProvider** completely and simplify the **DataSettingPage** component as so:

```
const DataSettingPage = ({title, label}) => {
  // I'm not sure what these are for so just leaving them here.
  const { layoutValue, chartValue, MainPage } = useContext(CommonStateContext);
  const [changeLayout] = layoutValue;
  const [chart] = chartValue;
  
  // DELETE
  // const { SetTitle, SetLabel, SetDatas, SetLabels } = useContext(SettingContext);

  
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(title)
  const [label, setLabel] = useState(label)
      
  {chart[index].key === "Bar" && (
    <BarChart
      title={title[id]} // <-- Where does your "id" come from??
      label={label[id]}
    />
  )}
```